# Como aumentar fonte do texto com NgSatinize?

Tags: angularjs, ionic, intel-xdk, css-font-size, sanitize

não estou conseguindo aumentar nem diminuir a fonte da minha noticia, que esta com o atributo NgSatinize, alguém sabe como modificar isso ? ou um outro caminho para satinizar meu html ?

Comment: Por favor, adicione **[um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** do seu código para melhores esclarecimentos.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta você deve estar com dificuldade de inserir `style inline` na tag dentro do `ng-bind`. Para que funcione corretamente você deve utilizar o `provider` `$sce` e função `trustAsHtml`. Segue exemplo abaixo:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('appExemploSanitize', ['ngSanitize']);

  angular
    .module('appExemploSanitize')
    .controller('NoticiaController', NoticiaController);

  NoticiaController.$inject = ['$sce'];

  function NoticiaController($sce) {
    var noticia = this;
    var texto;

    noticia.buscarNoticia = buscarNoticia;
    noticia.aumentarFonte = aumentarFonte;
    noticia.redefinir = redefinir;
    noticia.diminuirFonte = diminuirFonte;

    iniciar();

    function iniciar() {
      noticia.tamanho = 100;
      texto = '<div>O Facebook está tomando uma série de medidas para eliminar boatos e outros tipos de mentiras de seus feeds, disse na sexta-feira (18) o presidente da empresa, Mark Zuckerberg. A rede social enfrenta críticas por não ter evitado uma enxurrada de notícias falsas de serem compartilhadas na rede social antes da eleição norte-americana.</div>';
    }

    function buscarNoticia() {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml('<div style="font-size: ' + noticia.tamanho + '%"' + texto + '</div>');
    }

    function aumentarFonte(quantidade) {
      noticia.tamanho = noticia.tamanho + quantidade;
    }

    function redefinir(novaFonte) {
      noticia.tamanho = novaFonte;
    }

    function diminuirFonte(quantidade) {
      noticia.tamanho = noticia.tamanho - quantidade;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<div ng-app="appExemploSanitize">
  <div ng-controller="NoticiaController as noticia">
    <div ng-bind-html="noticia.buscarNoticia()">
    </div>
    <br>
    Tamanho: {{noticia.tamanho}}%
    <button ng-click="noticia.aumentarFonte(10)">+</button>
    <button ng-click="noticia.redefinir(100)" ng-disabled="noticia.tamanho === 100">100%</button>
    <button ng-click="noticia.diminuirFonte(10)">-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```